# Async CSLA Calls

Tags: csla

The 'standard' CSLA async server calls have typically been structured per the following:

Base class:

```
public static void GetMyObject(EventHandler<DataPortalResult<MyObject>> callback) {
  var dp = new DataPortal<MyObject>();
  dp.FetchCompleted += callback;
  dp.BeginFetch();
}
```

ViewModel:

```
protected override void OnInitialize(object parameter) {
  base.OnInitialize(parameter);
  base.IsBusy = true;
  MyObject.GetMyObject((o, e) => {
    if (HasNoException(e)) {
      Model = e.Object;
    }
    base.IsBusy = false;
  });
}
```

With the new async/await features, the format would be something like this:

```
public async static Task<MyObject> GetMyObject() {
  return await DataPortal.FetchAsync<MyObject>();
}
```

and

```
protected async override void OnInitialize(object parameter) {
  base.OnInitialize(parameter);
  base.IsBusy = true;
  Model = await MyObject.GetMyObjectAsync();
  base.IsBusy = false;
}
```

Should the callback pattern be considered deprecated at this point, or is it still useful for certain UI technologies? When doing a new project, I'd rather not have those methods in there if I can help it.

Comment: The question helped me get my async Task methods coded right.  Thanks Joe.

Comment: Glad it helped somebody!

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I prefer TAP methods over callbacks in all my code.

With `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`, most platforms support `async`. However, there are a few situations where neither TAP nor `Task` is available, e.g., Windows Phone 7.0, .NET CF, SL 3. I would only use callbacks if I had to support one of those platforms.